# How to update a facebook profile with R?

Tags: r, facebook

The twitteR package allows me to send tweets from R. All I needed to do was to set up a Twitter app and to use its authentification tokens and API.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/send-tweets-from-r-a-very-short-walkthrough/

Does the same exist for facebook? The only package I could find (facebookR) just retrieves info from facebook.

Otherwhise I could use system() and command lines methods

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-dating-now-available-us/

Comment: It's called rfacebook...

Comment: Searching for R-related resources can be difficult as `google: "r"` is a bit vague. For me, I often google for [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/)-based stuff (CRAN is *"Comprehensive R Archive Network"*), so `google: cran facebook` provides some thoughts on packages. Non-released packages or code does not pop-up, so another resource (which is not necessarily the best at times) is https://rseek.org. At other times, googling for `cran something` gives me recipes that include cranberries ... which can be distracting and beneficial in its own right :-)

Comment: Thanks r2evans, I will remember these tips. Christoph you are right, looking more closely, I found a "updateStatus" function in rfacebook, which is exactly what I need. Thanks to both of you.